# Pinch to zoom always use topleft corner as origin

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I added a UIImageView, which is smaller than the mainview and put two gestures in it.:

```
- (IBAction)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
- (IBAction)Pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

While "Pan" works perfect, dragging around the image, the pitch do not work as excepted. Every time I zoom in or out, the origin of the UIImageView snap back to the position I choosed in the storyboard. What do I miss? I copied the code from a sample [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) where it works perfect as expected.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are adding recognizers to the view?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I use the Storyboard. I generated a single view App. Add a UIImageView and than I dragged the Pinch Gesture onto that UIImageView and than I connected the Gesture with the code. I checked the "User Interaction enabled". That's all.

Comment: Ok, I copy and pasted your code. Added gesture recognizers in the storyboard by dragging them onto the view I want to scale/drag and everything works as expected. Do you have other gesture recognizers there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick is that the sample I used has "Use Auto Layout" disabled. The Autolayout feature prevents the code from apply new positions to a view (sometimes). Since XCode 4.3 the Autolayout feature is enabled automatically (which wasn't before) so when you rebuild a sample step by step, it will act different from the sample if you downloaded, if it's old enough.